# Cagan Model of Hyper Inflation: Zimbabwe Data Request

Tags: econometrics, inflation, data-request, applied-econometrics

[Cagan Model of Hyperinflation](http://pages.stern.nyu.edu/~cedmond/ge07pt/notes_cagan.pdf)

Could anyone guide me where I could find the data for Zimbabwe that would allow me to estimate the Beta parameters. Also, what regression method would be most suitable (I was thinking of a distributed lag).